# Python sas7bdat module - iterator or memory intensive?

Tags: python, sas

I'm wondering if the sas7bdat module in Python creates an iterator-type object or loads the entire file into memory as a list?  I'm interested in doing something line-by-line to a .sas7bdat file that is on the order of 750GB, and I *really* don't want Python to attempt to load the whole thing into RAM.

Example script:

```
from sas7bdat import SAS7BDAT
count = 0
with SAS7BDAT('big_sas_file.sas7bdat') as f:
 for row in f:
  count+=1
```

I can also use

```
it = f.__iter__()
```

but I'm not sure if that will still go through a memory-intensive data load.  Any knowledge of how sas7bdat works OR another way to deal with this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the relevant code on [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/jaredhobbs/sas7bdat/src/da1faa90d0b15c2c97a2a8eb86c91c58081bdd86/sas7bdat.py?fileviewer=file-view-default#sas7bdat.py-580).  The docstring describes iteration as a "generator", and looking at the code, it appears to be reading small pieces of the file rather than reading the whole thing at once.  However, I don't know enough about the file format to know if there are situations that could cause it to read a lot of data at once.

If you really want to get a sense of its performance before trying it on a giant 750G file, you should test it by creating a few sample files of increasing size and seeing how its performance scales with the file size.

Comment: Yea, using some combination of sys.getsizeof(), timing and top I was able to determine that a SAS7BDAT object is in fact a generator, so it doesn't use up much memory.  Thanks!

Comment: .sas7bdat tables are fixed-length files.  By my reasoning, even with the built-in SAS compression method (which simply removes whitespace padding), there should be no situation that would require large chunks of the file.